# Google Play Game Services: AbstractMethodError when run exported apk, while works ok if run from eclipse

Tags: java, android, apk, google-play-services, abstract-methods

I use Google Play Game Services lib in my project (as well as BaseGameUtils). My app works when I launch it from Eclipse, but today I exported it as apk, launched and got an AbstractMethodError. I tried to make apk both with eclipse and ant but had the same result. Eclipse-make and ant-make apk worked before I've added (or started using) Google Play Game Services in my project (it's not a new one).
How can I resolve this strange issue? It looks like gms code is incompatible with my binaries?

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.be.onViewAttachedToWindow(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:11948)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2415)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2422)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2422)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1209)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1006)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4404)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of error is usually due to using Proguard with a targetSDK that's too old. Try setting your application's target SDK to >= 17 and see if this fixes the problem.

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest ...>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
              android:targetSdkVersion="17"  />

    <application ...>
           ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but setting android:minSdkVersion="8"  android:targetSdkVersion="17" on both library and my project doesn't help - the same error.

Comment: By the way, if I export apk of Google game services example (type a number) it works! But my app using the same library - crashes.

Comment: Finally got it. Edited your answer and accepted it. I should not forget about project.properties

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate, I really do, that this question is nearly a year old! However I had the exact same issue, and it appears this is the only reference to this exact problem on the internet!

What was posted here didn't solve *my* issue, however it did point me in the direction of ProGuard. Since I have solved it, I wanted to post it so future people (perhaps me again) do not end up shouting at the monitor "Tertium, What did you see!" #xkcd.

Turns out I didn't have Proguard set up correctly. After much trial and error I found the following lines let me carry on:

```
 -keep class com.google.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.google.**
```

To add a bit of background context:

- I am building via Maven, android-maven-plugin
- It is a LibGDX based game

This may not be the most optimal solution, but it was one that got me out of a hole.